# Why does Propel create functions for retrieving some relational objects, but not all?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreign-keys, propel

In my database, I have a `user` table. This user table has several fields, amongst them `parent_user_id` and `user_class_id`, both foreign keys, neither of them are part of the primary key. In my BaseUser.php, it lists the foreign keys as follows:

```
protected $aUserRelatedByUserParentId;
protected $aUserClass;
```

Similarly, I have `getUserClass()` and `setUserClass()` but I do not have `getUserParent()` and `setUserParent()`. Rather, I have `getUserParentId() and setUserParentId()`. Is there a reason for this and if so, can I override it in the schema.xml? Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Autogenerated by PropelSchemaReverseTask class.-->
<database name="test" defaultIdMethod="native">
  <table name="user" phpName="User" idMethod="native">
    <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="parent_user_id" phpName="ParentUserId" type="INTEGER" required="true"/>
    <column name="name" phpName="Name" type="VARCHAR" size="45" required="true"/>
    <column name="description" phpName="Description" type="VARCHAR" size="45" required="true"/>
    <column name="user_class_id" phpName="UserClassId" type="INTEGER" required="true"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="user_class" name="fk_user_class">
      <reference local="user_class_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="user" name="fk_user_parent">
      <reference local="parent_user_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <index name="fk_user_parent_idx">
      <index-column name="parent_user_id"/>
    </index>
    <index name="fk_user_class_idx">
      <index-column name="user_class_id"/>
    </index>
    <vendor type="mysql">
      <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
    </vendor>
  </table>
  <table name="user_class" phpName="UserClass" idMethod="native">
    <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="name" phpName="Name" type="VARCHAR" size="45" required="true"/>
    <column name="permissions" phpName="Permissions" type="VARCHAR" size="45" required="true"/>
    <vendor type="mysql">
      <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
    </vendor>
  </table>
</database>
```

Comment: Can we see the relevant part of your XML schema (the part for `user` and any related tables)? - edit it into your question.

Comment: I added a schema.xml with the two tables in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just generated your schema in my own Propel environment, and found that you should currently have this:

```
/* @var $user User */
$user = new User();
$user->getUserRelatedByParentUserId();
$user->getUserClass();
```

I notice that you have `phpName` attributes on various columns - I'd recommend removing them, since you're requesting the defaults that would be generated anyway.

However, you're on the right track - try this:

```
<foreign-key foreignTable="user" name="fk_user_parent" phpName="ParentUser">
  <reference local="parent_user_id" foreign="id"/>
</foreign-key>
```

I'm assuming you're happy with the default relation name given to UserClass, so that doesn't change. However, for the self-join, I've added a custom relation name, which should give you `$user->getParentUser()`.

Incidentally, I expect you're using the `name` attributes on the FK definitions to give custom names to your constraints. That's fine if you want control over this, but I tend to let Propel name them as it wishes. If you are happy with that, they can be removed from the schema.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. I wish Propel had some way of merging custom edits to the schema.xml with the reverse-engineered schema.xml. I like to make my changes in the database over the XML.

Comment: You're welcome. What you could do is to make the changes in your XML, and then use the Migrations feature to modify your database in a controlled way. I think that's the standard approach with most ORMs. In a way, the database becomes the property of the ORM, and then you control the ORM's settings - it tends to be easier that way.

Comment: Well Hibernate (which is what we are migrating from), allows you to have a file of custom changes to your schema and you can reverse engineer it as many times as you want, you won't lose your changes.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not aware of anything like it for the current version of Propel, but you could start a discussion on the mailing list for version 2, now out in alpha.

Comment: I will definitely consider it!